# Xilinx DDS IP for modulating a carrier

Tags: xilinx, dds

I explored XIlinx IP for [DDS](http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/DDS_Compiler.htm), and am able to get 2 different frequencies (samples) based on the input clock. But what I want is to frequency modulate the clock itself.

So basically when I say I have to modulate the clock it means, the clock duration will  change based on a sine wave. So when the amplitude of sine wave increase, the clock period should increase, similarly when the amplitude of sine wave decreases,  the duration of the clock would start decreasing and so on...

Any suggestion here ?

Comment: I think with the normal clock nets you wont get to an solution. The DCM can be changed by logic, but they use much too long to stabilize in order to be used for this purpose.  You could try to make a asynchronous design that contains a oscillating loop and change the delay by logic. The more element you add to the loop the slower the clock will get. Problem: It will not be very stable, I think.

Comment: What are the frequencies involved?  How are you planning on getting a sine wave into the FPGA?  And why would you modulate your career rather than a carrier?  If you modulate your career with a sine wave then you should expect your profession to be a roller coaster ride.

Comment: Oh, shucks.  @W5VO fixed the spelling mistakes I was making a funny over.  :)

Answer (score 1):

A direct digital synthesizer (DDS) is an example of a numerically-controlled oscillator (NCO), in which the output frequency is proportional to a numeric (digital) input. If you want to modulate the frequency, you simply need to vary the numbers you feed into the DDS in a periodic way. There are many ways to accomplish this.